# Why are Vortigaunts violent in Half Life 1, but peaceful in Half Life 2?

Tags: video-games, half-life

Why are vortigaunts violent in Half Life 1, but peaceful in Half Life 2?

[image]

Comment: There is one area in HL1 where the vortigaunts are peaceful (i.e. they won't attack Gordon Freeman unless he attacks first).  Unfortunately, it's so late in the game that there's a strong tendency on the part of the player to "shoot first and ask questions later".

Comment: @ReginaldBlue Which area is that?

Comment: I was afraid someone would ask that... according to the strategywiki for half-life... the 'segment' is called "Interloper" and the area is called "Factory".  Quoting from the wiki:  "They are passive until attacked".

Comment: @ReginaldBlue If memory serves me well, the Vorts won't attack Freeman when he is in Xen, in general. This is true even at the beginning of the game, when the player is teletransported to Xen for a brief moment right after the resonance cascade.

Comment: @MarcRanolfi Correct, the scene in question plays out on the homeworld of the invading aliens.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Vortigaunts in Half-Life 1 are an enslaved (or merely subservient) species ruled by the Nihilanth after they were driven from their homeworld by the Combine. The green collars they wear in Half-Life 1 are evidence of this slavery.

[image: the HL1 "alien_slave"]

Comment: As well as the bracelets they wear. Periodically in HL2, you’ll hear them thank Freeman for releasing them from their bondage.

Comment: Is that ever mentioned in the games?